# Dafny: Verification of the most simple array summation does not work. Can somebody explain me why?

Tags: arrays, addition, dafny

When I have three arrays and c[j] := b[h] + a[i]. The verification c[j] == b[h] + a[i] does not work. Can somebody please explain me why? It is assured that all indices are in range and all three arrays are int arrays.
Here is my code:

```
method addThreeArrays(a: array<int>, b: array<int>, c: array<int>, h: int, i: int, j: int)
  modifies c
  requires 0 <= h < a.Length
  requires 0 <= i < b.Length
  requires 0 <= j < c.Length
  
  ensures c[j] == a[h] + b[i]
  {
    c[j] := a[h] + b[i];
  }
```

I expected the "ensures" line to be true. But Dafny gives the error. "Postcondition" might not hold. I just want to understand where my error is. Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Dafny arrays are allocated on the heap, they are allowed to alias. So it is possible to call your method with, for example, `c` and `a` pointing to the same array in memory. Also, it's possible that `j == h`. In that scenario, the postcondition may not hold since writing to `c[j]` also wrote to `a[h]` (since `c` and `a` point to the same array and `j == h`).

You can fix this by adding a precondition that `a != c` and `b != c`.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote your example to the Dafny project and how we would solve it using code actions:
https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/3102

I reproduce the detailed solution here to [compute a weakest precondition](https://dafny.org/latest/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-verification-debugging).

---

Making the assertion explicit would result in

```
  {
    c[j] := a[h] + b[i];
    assert c[j] == a[h] + b[i];
  }
```

Now, we cannot just "move the assert up", because we would otherwise have to reason about the state of the heap after the assignment, and old@ cannot refer to a label defined afterwards yet.
So, the next step would be to introduce the label and do the weakest precondition calculus below the assignment

```
  {
    label before: // Added
    c[j] := a[h] + b[i];
    assert old@before(a[h] + b[i]) == a[h] + b[i]; // Added, now failing
    assert c[j] == a[h] + b[i];
  }
```

The nice thing about that is that it would help the user discover the "old" syntax in a natural way.
Because the weakest precondition now sees two more potentially conflicting references, it could suggest the following code action to remove the reference to the heap after the assignment:

```
  {
    label before: // Added
    c[j] := a[h] + b[i];
    assert old@before(a[h] + b[i]) == (if a == c && j == h then old@before(a[h] + b[i]) else a[h]) + (if b == c && j == i then old@before(a[h] + b[i]) else b[i]); 
    assert c[j] == a[h] + b[i];
  }
```

Now, because this expression does not refer at all to the heap after the assignment `c[j}`, the weakest precondition calculus would be able to move this assertion before and remove the `old@` expressions.

```
  {
    assert a[h] + b[i] == (if a == c && j == h then a[h] + b[i] else a[h]) + (if b == c && j == i then a[h] + b[i] else b[i]); // Just added, now failing.
    label before:
    c[j] := a[h] + b[i];
    assert old@before(a[h] + b[i]) == (if a == c && j == h then old@before(a[h] + b[i]) else a[h]) + (if b == c && j == i then old@before(a[h] + b[i]) else b[i]); 
    assert old@before(a[h] + b[i]) == a[h] + b[i];
    assert c[j] == a[h] + b[i];
  }
```

and eventually move it to a requires of the method. The user can then refine this weakest precondition so that they only keep `a != c && b != c` if they wanted to. Or not.

Comment: Thank you for putting so much effort in helping me! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding another answer as well because I think it's independent. The postcondition refers by default to the heap at the end of the method. You can make the postcondition to hold by refering to the dereference of `a` and `b` at the beginning of the heap, by inserting `old(...)` like this:

```
method addThreeArrays(a: array<int>, b: array<int>, c: array<int>, h: int, i: int, j: int)
  modifies c
  requires 0 <= h < a.Length
  requires 0 <= i < b.Length
  requires 0 <= j < c.Length
  
  ensures c[j] == old(a[h] + b[i])
  {
    c[j] := a[h] + b[i];
  }
```

That works like a charm and is exactly what your method is doing.
Credits to Rustan Leino for pointing me to this solution.